# Javascript: Able to parse data with 'M' in millions or without correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code in angular that get data from google finance. However, it can get data for vo and avvo correctly if M or K exists which represent millions and thousands. If without it, it can not shows the value properly.

How can I handle both cases to take data correctly?

example of data:

```
// [
{
"id": "549805688244420"
,"t" : "AZG"
,"e" : "SGX"
,"l" : "0.060"
,"l_fix" : "0.060"
,"l_cur" : "SGD0.06"
,"s": "0"
,"ltt":"5:04PM GMT+8"
,"lt" : "Jun 19, 5:04PM GMT+8"
,"lt_dts" : "2017-06-19T17:04:01Z"
,"c" : "0.000"
,"c_fix" : "0.000"
,"cp" : "0.00"
,"cp_fix" : "0.000"
,"ccol" : "chb"
,"pcls_fix" : "0.06"
,"eo" : ""
,"delay": ""
,"op" : ""
,"hi" : ""
,"lo" : ""
,"vo" : "0.00"
,"avvo" : "2,087.00"
,"hi52" : "0.21"
,"lo52" : "0.05"
,"mc" : "5.75M"
,"pe" : ""
,"fwpe" : ""
,"beta" : ""
,"eps" : "-0.22"
,"shares" : "92.63M"
,"inst_own" : ""
,"name" : "8Telecom International Holdings Co. Ltd."
,"type" : "Company"
}
]
```

It will shows vo as N/A and avvo as 2.0. 
if data as below:

```
// [
{
"id": "381558643124633"
,"t" : "U11"
,"e" : "SGX"
,"l" : "23.25"
,"l_fix" : "23.25"
,"l_cur" : "SGD23.25"
,"s": "0"
,"ltt":"11:24AM GMT+8"
,"lt" : "May 19, 11:24AM GMT+8"
,"lt_dts" : "2017-05-19T11:24:19Z"
,"c" : "-0.09"
,"c_fix" : "-0.09"
,"cp" : "-0.39"
,"cp_fix" : "-0.39"
,"ccol" : "chr"
,"pcls_fix" : "23.34"
,"eo" : ""
,"delay": ""
,"op" : "23.24"
,"hi" : "23.40"
,"lo" : "23.22"
,"vo" : "1.34M"
,"avvo" : "2.47M"
,"hi52" : "24.02"
,"lo52" : "17.41"
,"mc" : "38.29B"
,"pe" : "12.49"
,"fwpe" : ""
,"beta" : ""
,"eps" : "1.86"
,"shares" : "1.64B"
,"inst_own" : ""
,"name" : "United Overseas Bank Ltd"
,"type" : "Company"
}
]
```

the vo and avvo data is taking correctly.

```
angular.module('myapp.factories').factory('$stockDataFactory',
  ['$q', '$filter', '$webServicesFactory',
    function ($q, $filter, $webServicesFactory) {
      return {
        getStockDetails: function (stock) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          $webServicesFactory.getNotParsed(
            "https://www.google.com/finance/info",
            {},
            {
              infotype: "infoquoteall",
              q: stock.market+":"+stock.symbol
            }
          ).then(
            function success(response) {
              response = JSON.parse("["+response.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ' ').split('[').splice(1,1)[0]);
              stock = response[0];
        var formatedData = {
                  volume: stock.vo,
                  averageDailyVolume: stock.avvo
           };
```

**html**

```
  <div class="row row-center">
    <div class="col boldText">Volume: </div>
    <div class="col col-21">{{stock.volume || 'N/A'}}</div>
    <div class="col boldText">Avg. Vol: </div>
    <div class="col col-21">{{(stock.averageDailyVolume | shrinkNumber: 2) || 'N/A'}}</div>
  </div>
```

**Shrinknumber in javascript**

```
angular.module('chaishen.factories').filter("shrinkNumber", function($filter) {
  return function(number, fractionSize) {

    if(number === null) return null;
    if(number === 0) return "0.000";

    // default number of decimals for values >1000 or <-1000 if not set in view
    if(!fractionSize || fractionSize < 0)
      fractionSize = 1;

    var abs = Math.abs(number);
    var rounder = Math.pow(10,fractionSize);
    var isNegative = number < 0;
    var key = '';
    var powers = [
      {key: "Q", value: Math.pow(10,15)},
      {key: "T", value: Math.pow(10,12)},
      {key: "B", value: Math.pow(10,9)},
      {key: "M", value: Math.pow(10,6)},
      {key: "K", value: 1000}
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < powers.length; i++) {

      var reduced = abs / powers[i].value;

      //reduced = Math.round(reduced * rounder) / rounder;
      reduced = Math.round(abs * rounder) / rounder;

      if(reduced >= 1){
        abs = reduced;
        key = powers[i].key;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(number >= 1000) {
      //return abs + key;
      return abs;
    }
    else if(number <= -1000) {
      //return '-' + abs + key;
      return '-' + abs;
    }
    else {
      //return $filter('number')(((isNegative ? '-' : '') + abs + key), 3);
      return $filter('number')(((isNegative ? '-' : '') + abs), 3);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a JSFiddle or a working code sample?

Comment: @daan.desmedt it is a bit hard as it involve many files. But I just want to know in javascript, how we can handle both with abbreviation K and M and without correctly

Comment: @daan.desmedt I added the html that is related. Thanks a lot